# How to create a automated folder structure with permission set using Google Drive APIs

Tags: google-drive-android-api

I'm trying to create a project structure that has a shared folder and a private folder. Everyone has access to the shared folder and everyone in the group has access to only their private folder. Whats the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Google Drive Files and Folder Permission](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-permissions) you can set the level of the availability of your files and folders.

> Types, roles and values: how the permissions work
>
> Lists of permissions are available for each file and folder in Drive.
>   Each permission specifies a [type](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions#resource), role, and emailAddress or domain,
>   permitting a level of access to a file or folder. These values work
>   together to limit the access appropriately. The type limits access to
>   a set of users. The email address and domain fields specify which
>   users can have access. Finally, the role gives these users the ability
>   to do something to the file, like read it. When combined, these
>   properties define a complete permission.